# In sails/waterline get maximum value of a column in a database agnostic way

Tags: javascript, orm, sails.js, waterline

While using sails as ORM (version 1.0), I notice that there is a function called [`Model.avg`](https://next.sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/avg) (as well as sum). - However there is not a maximum or minimum function to get the maximum or minimum from a column in a model; so it seems this is not necessary because it is covered by other functions already?

Now in my database I need to get the "maximum id" in a list; and I have it working *for postgresql* by using a native query:

```
const maxnum = await Order.getDatastore().sendNativeQuery('SELECT MAX(\"orderNr\") FROM \"order\"')
```

While this isn't the most difficult thing, it is not what I truly want: it is limited to only sql-based datastores (so we wouldn't be able to move easily to mongodb); and the syntax might actually be even different for another sql database type.

So I wonder - can this be transformed in such a way it doesn't rely on `sendNativeQuery`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `.query()` to execute a raw SQL query using the specified model's datastore and if u want u can try `pg` , an NPM package used for communicating with PostgreSQL databases:

```
Pet.query('SELECT pet.name FROM pet WHERE pet.name = $1', [ 'dog' ] 
  ,function(err, rawResult) {
    if (err) { return res.serverError(err); }

    sails.log(rawResult);
    // (result format depends on the SQL query that was passed in, and 
       the adapter you're using)

    // Then parse the raw result and do whatever you like with it.

   return res.ok();
});
```

Comment: That's not "database agnostic" though, which was part of the ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `limit` and `order` options waterline provides to get a single Model with a maximal value (then just extract that value).

```
const orderModel = await Order.find({
    where: {},
    select: ['orderNr'],
    limit: 1,
    sort: 'orderNr DESC'
});
console.log(orderModel.orderNr);
```

Like most things in Waterline, it's probably not as efficient as an SQL `SELECT MAX` query (or some equivalent in mongo, etc), but it should allow swapping out the database with no maintenance. Last note, don't forget to handle the case of no models found.

Comment: in the case of a limit of 1 are database technologies clever enough to "not sort the database"? - In my case having around a million entries this might otherwise slow down the process.

Comment: I've got some volume issues as well... in my case, I use mongo, and if you have an index for that ordering on that collection, it's a lightning fast operation. If no index, it will indeed have to check every record. I don't know the details of implementing in SQL databases, but I would bet it is similar.

Comment: This is btw not working: 
ERROR:
{ UsageError: Invalid criteria.
Details:
  The provided criteria contains an unrecognized property: 'order'
* * *
In previous versions of Sails/Waterline, this criteria _may_ have worked, since keywords like `limit` were allowed to sit alongside attribute names that are really supposed to be wrapped inside of the `where` clause.  But starting in Sails v1.0/Waterline 0.13, if a `limit`, `skip`, `sort`, etc is defined, then any <attribute name> vs. <constraint> pairs should be explicitly contained inside the `where` clause.
* * *`

Comment: Not sure if it will solve the problem in 1.0... but I mixed up the key names `order` and `sort`. I'll update to `sort` which I know is correct in older versions of waterline. It may be worth a try in sails 1.0.